# Most Efficient way to compare variables in C++

Tags: c++

I had got a task to make a code for the following question.

> Write a lottery game application that will generate three random numbers each between 0 and 9. The user should guess three numbers and the program should compare each of the user's guess to the three random and display an appropriate output based on whether they got:
>
> - anyone matching
> - two matching
> - three matching, not in order
> - three matching in exact order
> - or no matches at all

I have been trying different methods to do this, one way that I found out was using if else if statements, But the code looks very inefficient.

The other method I tried doing was using for loop but then there is a logical error with it.

I was using following code.

```
int inputarray[3];
int randomnumberarray[3];
//here goes simple if condition for checking case of all same numbers in exact order//
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++ ) /*this condition is applied after checking the numbers to be equal in exact order*/
{
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j ++ )
        {
                if ( randomnumberarray[j] == inputarray[i] )
                        ++repition ;
        }
}
```

But using the above condition it gets weird if a user enters same digit 3 times or if the random digits are same.

Any help would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Please do not tag languages that are unrelated to the question.

Comment: Sorry , Asking a question for the first time here.

Comment: Write smaller functions, such as "is_number_in_array(...)", "are_arrays_equal(...)" etc. Then you can write you test logic almost like pseudocode/English, using these funcions.

Comment: It might help if you edit your question and reformat the problem statement. It looks like a bullet list that is joined together, so it is difficult to see what and how many outputs/calculations are required

Comment: Sorry I am new here , can't find the right options.

Comment: One of the problems I faced was:

Suppose that Random Lottery number is : 256

User Enters : 666

My program says you got 3 matching digits :P

Answer (score 1):

If you hate if-else-if ladder, my quick answer to your question is as follows.
[@Rao Ubaid 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653019/most-efficient-way-to-compare-variables-in-c/52654653#52654653) is almost right, but we must throw away already matched guessed values like [this demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nVLDzTm8a3CDOPZ3) to avoid double counting:

```
int calcScore(
    const std::vector<std::size_t>& ans,
    std::vector<std::size_t> guess)
{        
    assert((ans.size() == 3) && (guess.size() == 3));

    if((ans[0] == guess[0]) && (ans[1] == guess[1]) && (ans[2] == guess[2])) {
        return 4;
    }

    auto score = 0;

    for (const auto ans_i : ans)
    {
        for (auto it = guess.begin(); it != guess.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it == ans_i)
            {
                score += 1;
                guess.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return score;    
}
```

The next considerations are writing tests and performance tunings.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do it.
Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int check ( int a , int n[3] )
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
    {
        if ( a == n[i] )
        {
            return 1 ;
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}

int main ()
{
    //PRE-PROGRAM DECLARATIONS
    int n[3] , a[3] , input , repition ;
    repition = 0 ;
    srand(time(NULL)) ;
    n[0] = rand() % 10 ;
    n[1] = rand() % 10 ;
    n[2] = rand() % 10 ;

    //TESTING STUFF GOES HERE
    //cout << n[0] << n[1] << n[2] << endl ;

    //OUTPUT, INPUT, and PROCESSING
    cout << "Enter your Guess Here : " ;
    cin >> input ;
    a[0] = input / 100 ;
    a[1] = ( input % 100 ) / 10 ;
    a[2] = ( input % 10 ) ;


    //CONDITIONS
    if ( a[0] == n[0] && a[1] == n[1] && a[2] == n[2] )
    {
        repition = 4 ;
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
        {
            repition = repition + check( n[i] , a ) ;
        }
    }

    //OUTPUT
    switch (repition)
    {
        case 4:
            cout << "All digits correct - Exact Order!\n" ;
            break ;
        case 3:
            cout << "All digits correct - Different Order!\n" ;
            break ;
        case 2:
            cout << "Two digits correct!\n" ;
            break ;
        case 1:
            cout << "Only One digit Correct!\n" ;
            break ;
        case 0:
            cout << "Sorry Try Again!\n" ;
            break ;
        default :
            cout << "Something is terrible!\n" ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be sure, I should tell you that there is still double counting. For instance, if the lottery number is 666 and user enters 256, your program says “All digits correct - Different Order!”. Demo is here, https://wandbox.org/permlink/pHT5F0SGMbqeJhTc . I am afraid that you are a lottery computer programmer. I hope that this is just a homework problem.